# Core data: detect when child has been deleted

Tags: ios, core-data

In my app, I have a `Result` entity, which can contains multiple `Expense` entities.

Each `Expense` has an amount, and my `Result` contains the sum of the Expenses.

I need to calculate automatically that sum when an `Expense` is added or deleted.

I have succeeded in doing that when my `Expense` is added, overriding `didChangeValueForKey` from the `Expense` `NSManagedObject`. However, even if the method is called when the delete has taken effect, the reference to the `Result` object is nil. I have an idea using `willChangeValueForKey` to store the reference of my `Result` object, but I find this pretty dirty.

Do you have a better idea so that the Result object gets notified when one of its child is deleted?

Comment: what about creating NSFetchedResutsController for Result and each time something in it changes , controller will tell you

Comment: Did you read the `NSManagedObject` documentation for `didChangeValueForKey:`?  Just in case you missed it, It says this: **You must not override this method**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to listen to NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification like that:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
  addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(dataModelHasChanged:) 
         name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification 
       object:managedObjectContext];
```

Every time a change happens you will be able to detect it this way:

```
- (void)dataModelHasChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *deletedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *insertedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];

// Do something in response to this
```

}

Comment: this is good but I store the result back in Result object, which would result in an infinite loop

Comment: Why would it cause an infinite loop?
Just detect if it was deleted/inserted and then deduct/add the sum accordingly

Comment: No infinite loop, but you are missing a user-info key.  And, this only updates the value after a user-event (i.e., pending changes have been processed).  If you are going to do active cache management, you need to consider other edge cases as well.  Some of the most obvious: Are you going to always do the computation?  If not, how are you going to decide?  What about handling objects that are faults?  Are you going to fire a fault to get the data, or will it be cached?  If you cache it, what will you do it the object turns into a fault?  etc, etc, etc... Cache management is hard.

Comment: if I check the Expense being deleted, I don't have access to the Result object because it is already nil. If I check the Result being modified, and then calculate the sum and modify it, it will result in an infinite loop. If you have an idea on that part I would gladly take it!

Comment: So every time you delete an Expense this method is called twice: once for the result and once for the Expense. Right?

Comment: The method is called once. In the updated objects I have a reference for the Result object, and in the deleted objects I have the reference of the deleted Expense.

Comment: Ok.. So if you update the Result you can recalculate the Expenses. It will now have a new set of expenses

Comment: I don't have a reference of the Result from the deleted Expense, and changing the Result sum using the updated Result will fire a new NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification and cause the infinite loop.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Just calculate the what you want from the Result. You don't need what you don't have you need to calculate it from what you do have - i.e the exist expenses. Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Ok you made me think more, I think I have found a way. I trigger the calculation only when I know that I have deleted an Expense, i.e. when I have a deleted Expense AND an updated Result. Thank you!

Comment: Amazing! that's what I've meant :)

Comment: Will appreciate if you can approve my answer than mate

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the sum in `Result` should be a computed property. Storing the sum in the database seems redundant.

Note that this can be very efficient using KVC:

```
let sum = self.expenses.valueForKeyPath("@sum.amount")
```

Comment: Having heavy computation to do, as I later compute sums of Results and other stats, I need to precompute as much as I can.

Comment: You'd be surprised how fast Core Data can do this kind of computations. I have built a very complex analysis model that actually performed very well with this pattern, even including more complex calculations involving functions and recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add computed properties to the `Expenses` and manage the desired side effects there.

```
@NSManaged private var storedAmount: NSNumber

var amount: NSNumber {
   set { 
      amount = newValue
      storedAmount = amount
      // do your computation and update Result
   }
   get {  return storedAmount }
}
```